# unicode symbol breaks formatting in c++20

Tags: c++, c++20, stdformat

I started learning c++ and what seemed to be a piece of cake task turned out to be a big headache.

I noticed than a unicode symbol in my formatting eats a piece of column width. Even more when I was preparing a minimal reproducible example for this question I noted that the more symbols I add, the more width is eaten.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <format>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << std::format("|{0:30}|{1:30}|\n", "Constant", "Approximate value");
  std::cout << std::format("|{0:30}|{1:30.5f}|\n", "p", std::numbers::pi);
  std::cout << std::format("|{0:30}|{1:30.5f}|\n", "π", std::numbers::pi);
  std::cout << std::format("|{0:30}|{1:30.5f}|\n", "ππ", std::numbers::pi);
  std::cout << std::format("|{0:30}|{1:30.5f}|\n", "πππ", std::numbers::pi);
  return 0;
}
```

Resulting in

```
|Constant                      |Approximate value             |
|p                             |                       3.14159|
|π                            |                       3.14159|
|ππ                          |                       3.14159|
|πππ                        |                       3.14159|
```

I would really appreciate your explanation of what the mechanism is behind this phenomenon. BTW please find the interactive example here: https://godbolt.org/z/s9Mf7KPYz

Comment: Because `std::format` is not unicode-aware and thinks that π is two chars with codes 0x03 and 0xc0. But when your unicode-aware terminal renders it, it draws one char.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade many thanks! Sounds reasonable. Is there a way to reliably overcome that effect?

Comment: FWIW clang + stdlibc++ works fine, if that's an option for you: https://godbolt.org/z/cMq8Gehq4

Comment: Hmm... gcc trunk also works: https://godbolt.org/z/dcMej1YKP

Comment: I would expect this to depend on your locale settings.

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade It's supposed to be unicode-aware, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I just double checked, and I'm actually wrong. Since the argument is neither a floating point number nor an integer, the left alignment should be the default.
This had to be a compiler bug since simply changing the compiler version gave the [right output](https://godbolt.org/z/x1zaehbEq).

`{0:30}` means that the variable `0` will be followed by `30` spaces.
For the separator (`|`) to be alined you can use `{0:<30}`:

```
std::format("|{0:<30}|{1:30.5f}|\n", "p", std::numbers::pi)
```

To align the variable `0` left and add padding so that the length of the line is `30`. ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/spec#Fill_and_align))

Live on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y9Kjx8zTo).